# Is it possible to store a pdf file in a mysql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, pdf, base64

I'm currently looking for a solution to store pdf files in a mysql database.

I tried to store them as base64 string or as byte array but both havn't worked for any reason. I'm using a longblob in the mysql to store the data.

Before inserting it to the mysql

```cs
byte[] myfile = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

To get is from the mysql

```cs
   byte[] buffer = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
            con.Close();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"test.pdf", FileMode.Create);
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

I really hope someone can help me with this issue!

Comment: `but both havn't worked for any reason` Comments like that tell us nothing.  You should post the code that doesnt work and tell us ***how*** it doesnt work (exception?  wrong result?, seems to do nothing?).  The code posted is not enough - beyond just reading the file, there is the SQL, the column type etc

Comment: in general it is more easy to save the pdf on disk and save a path in the database.. Also that way you also dont have to think how to stream the pdf correctly to the application to open and or display it.

Comment: Any binary type works fine. We have been storing blobs in Databases for decades now. As for your problem, we need a better description then "does not work" to help you.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The "Store on disk, mark in DB" approahc has it's own downsides. And it is definitely harder to do then just adding a varbinary column. And as middle ground, we may have Filestream: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/

Comment: @Christopher You link is about SQL Server (MSSQL) ... `MySQL <> SQL Server (MSSQL)`..

Comment: @RaymondNijland "And as middle ground, we **may** have Filestream:" And even if we do not, a (var)bianry is still easier the co-storage one disk!

Comment: Converting back and forth from binary has more steps and easier for something to go wrong and more memory intensive as well as possible disposable issues

Comment: @Christopher  well you could simply even use C# webbrowser object and use [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) as it can load a base64 encoded PDF ... There are more ways to rome even when this is a "hacky" one....

Comment: *"And even if we do not, a (var)bianry is still easier the co-storage one disk! "* @Christopher in general using a database as filesystem is slower then filesystem storage, there are some exceptions for files smaller then ~1 MB in size or when "hundred thousand" files exists in one dir which also makes filesystem slower..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Why would you base64 encode perfectly good binary data that can be transmitted as perfectly good binary data? Base64 is for when you can not transmit the raw binary data. So I usually leave it to the details of the Data Transmission protocolls.

Comment: *"Why would you base64 encode perfectly good binary data that can be transmitted as perfectly good binary data?"* @Christopher i know, but good question ask the topicstarter he mentioned base64 first in this question..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Then you should ask him that and not me. I gave the answer to use binary. He propably only tried base64 because he did not know better or had some issues. He has the excuse of lacking knowledge. What is yours?

Comment: @Christopher not going futher into this comment *"war"*, The topicstarter should provide more details so we can stop guessing how or why...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 schools of thought for storing BLOBS in/with a Database. And a 3rd one that tries to combine both, but is not avalible for MySQL last I checked. Still [this article on Nr. 3](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/) will get you up to speed.

For storing in DB it is simple:

1. Add a table for the Primary Key, filename and the binary data to the DB.
2. Extract the filename and binary data on teh C# side.
3. Store the Filename and data in the Database. Have the Primary key be auto-generated as usual.

For storing besides the DB in the Filesystem:

1. Add a table for Primary key, original filename and local path in the DB. The local name can be different, as more then 1 person might name their file "test.pdf"
2. Optionally add a Hash value for the binary, so you can avoid double storage. But that is secondary.
3. Get a randomized, unused name for the Document on teh disk. Store that and the Original Filename in the Database. And the binary data on said disk.